# LISP Changing a global variable value in a local function

Tags: lisp, global-variables

I am a novice in the field of lisp... i am writing a code to solve the 8 puzzle in bfs...

I want to store the visited lists in a global list and change its value regularly from within a function...

```
(defparameter *vlist* nil)
(defun bfs-core(node-list)
        (let (cur-node tmp-node-list)
            (if (null node-list)
                NIL
                (progn
                ;       (if (= 1 (length node-list)) 
                    (setq cur-node (car node-list))
                    (setq tmp-node-list (cdr node-list))
                    (if (goalp  cur-node)
                        cur-node
                    ((setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*))
                       (bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node))))))
                    )
                )
            )
```

The defparameter one is my global variable... and witjin the function i want to change its value with setq... i have also used defvar, setf,set and all possible combinations.....
Can anyone help me out????

Comment: Your code already includes an assignment to `*vlist*` using `setq`.  It's `(setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*)`.  It's not clear what you're asking.  Your syntax isn't right, though.  `if` should look like `(if (goalp cur-node) cur-node (progn (setq ...) (bfs-core ...)))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code (reformatted for standard Lisp style):

```
(defparameter *vlist* nil)
(defun bfs-core (node-list)
  (let (cur-node tmp-node-list)
    (if (null node-list)
        NIL
        (progn
          ;       (if (= 1 (length node-list)) 
          (setq cur-node (car node-list))
          (setq tmp-node-list (cdr node-list))
          (if (goalp  cur-node)
              cur-node
              ((setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*))
               (bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node)))))))))
```

Your code as one clear problem.

The form `((setq *vlist* ...) (bfs-core ...))` ends up being a function call.  When you have a form like `(exp1 exp2 exp3)` then `exp1` is a function applied to parameter values of `exp2` and `exp3`.  Your `exp1` is `(setq *vlist* ...)` which doesn't evaluate to a function and, of course, you never wanted it to.

A rewritten version of your code, that at least would remove the misplaced function call, is:

```
(defparameter *vlist* nil)
(defun bfs-core (node-list)
  (let (cur-node tmp-node-list)
    (if (null node-list)
        NIL
        (progn
          ;       (if (= 1 (length node-list)) 
          (setq cur-node (car node-list))
          (setq tmp-node-list (cdr node-list))
          (if (goalp  cur-node)
              cur-node
              (progn
                (setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*))
                (bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node)))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can change global variables from inside functions:

```
[1]> (defparameter *visited-lists* nil)
*VISITED-LISTS*
[2]> *visited-lists* 
NIL
[3]> (defun change-global-value ()
  (setf *visited-lists* (append (list 'new-value) 
                                *visited-lists* )))
CHANGE-GLOBAL-VALUE
[4]> *visited-lists* 
NIL
[5]> (change-global-value) 
(NEW-VALUE)
[6]> *visited-lists* 
(NEW-VALUE)
[7]> (change-global-value) 
(NEW-VALUE NEW-VALUE)
[8]> *visited-lists* 
(NEW-VALUE NEW-VALUE)
```

But let's look at your code some more:

```
(defun bfs-core(node-list)
        (let (cur-node tmp-node-list)
            (if (null node-list)
                NIL
                (progn
                ;       (if (= 1 (length node-list)) 
                    (setq cur-node (car node-list))
                    (setq tmp-node-list (cdr node-list))
                    (if (goalp  cur-node)
                        cur-node
                    ((setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*))
                       (bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node))))))
                    )
                )
            )
```

First, let's get closing parentheses on the correct lines, and remove the commented-out code. Most Lisp coders don't close their parens like braces in an ALGOL-style language:

```
(defun bfs-core(node-list)
  (let (cur-node tmp-node-list)
    (if (null node-list)
        NIL
      (progn
        (setq cur-node (car node-list))
        (setq tmp-node-list (cdr node-list))
        (if (goalp  cur-node)
            cur-node
          ((setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*))
           (bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node)))))))))
```

Now, we have a `nil` for the first branch of an `if`. We can change it to `unless`, which has a built-in `progn`, so we don't need that either:

```
(defun bfs-core(node-list)
  (let (cur-node tmp-node-list)
    (unless (null node-list) ;;changed this line to an unless, dropped nil, progn
      (setq cur-node (car node-list))
      (setq tmp-node-list (cdr node-list))
      (if (goalp  cur-node)
          cur-node
        ((setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*))
         (bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node))))))))
```

We're also using a `let` to set some variables to `nil`, and when we get inside the `unless`, we immediately set the variables to the values we actually want to work with. Let's switch it so that we only create the variables if we're going to use them:

```
(defun bfs-core(node-list)
  (unless (null node-list) ;;switched this line and the let below
    (let ((cur-node (car node-list)) ;;also set the variables inside the let
          (tmp-node-list) (cdr node-list))
      (if (goalp  cur-node)
          cur-node
        ((setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*))
         (bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node))))))))
```

Ok, we're already at much cleaner code. Yay!

Let's look at one of the calls here:

```
((setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*))
 (bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node))))
```

Did you mean to put this as a *single* call, and not two? There's a difference between that and this:

```
((setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*)))
(bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node)))
```

Do you see the difference? The first is a single statement; the second is two. You probably want the second, as you want to change `*vlist*`, then call `bfs-core`. And, to do *that*, you'll need `progn`:

```
(defun bfs-core(node-list)
  (unless (null node-list)
    (let ((cur-node (car node-list))
          (tmp-node-list) (cdr node-list))
      (if (goalp  cur-node)
          cur-node
        (progn (setq *vlist* (append cur-node *vlist*))
               (bfs-core (append tmp-node-list (expand cur-node))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are specific to the problem at hand.  As a general answer on how to change the value of a variable that is passed to a subroutine, it is possible if the variable is passed as a symbol:

```
(defun modify (x)
  (set x 100))

(setq d 1)         => value of d is 1
(modify 'd)        => value of d is 100
```

So, to use the terminology of pass by value and pass by reference and apply that to lisp:

```
(userfunction 'x)  is pass by reference,
(Userfunction x)   is pass by value.
```